# Is calling HttpServletResponse.addCookie() with the same cookie name safe?

Tags: java, servlets

Is calling

```
HttpServletResponse.addCookie();
```

(from servlet-api-2.5) multiple times using a cookie with the same name safe?

Safe in the sense of that there is a deterministic behavior, e.g. the subsequent calls will be ignored (the first wins) or the subsequent calls will always replace the cookie or something like that?

Example:

```
HttpServletResponse response = ...;
response.addCookie(new Cookie("foo", "bar"));
response.addCookie(new Cookie("foo", "42"));
```

Which value will be transferred to and stored by the browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated answer - as the comments from @skaffman and @Stephen C show this is not ideal practice.

The RFC Spec at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt states

> The NAME=VALUE attribute-value pair
>   must come first in each cookie.  **If an attribute appears
>   more than once in a    cookie, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

On Tomcat server, the behaviour is the actual headers sent to the browser:

> Set-Cookie: foo=bar
>   Set-Cookie: foo=42

Here foo gets overwritten. Reading the cookie later gives you 42.

Comment: All this would prove is that a specific implementation of `HttpServletResponse` does something. The API doesn't define the behaviour, though, so other implementations might do something else.

Comment: Well i've suggested the O/P try out on his server to verify the behaviour

Comment: well, it would have better to suggest that he not do it at all!  It is creating a potential portability issue.

Comment: I know about the undefined behavior in that RFC but have hoped for a better specification in the Servlet API (which is not covered by the Javadocs).

Answer (score 2):

Additional comment - note that setting different sub-domains on cookies with the same name in the same response changes the behavior. I just tested saving cookies with the same name but different sub-domains on latest versions of java 1.6/firefox/safari/chrome on my mac, and it behaved as expected, saving both cookies. I understand this behavior is not guaranteed by the spec, but just sayin' it may be helpful to be aware of it.